# how can we achieve accessibility for the component bottom sheet in react native?

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native, accessibility

We have implemented bottom sheet for iOS using third party component "reanimated-bottom-sheet"
This is not accessible in iOS.

we could get very little help from the documentation (https://reactnative.dev/docs/accessibility)

Anybody has insights on how we can achieve accessibility for the component bottom sheet ?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? We're considering switching all to popup modals

Comment: Any updated on this issue. Still couldn't perform testing automation because of this issue.